# iOS app Free for 1 month after that monthly Payable Subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am planing to publish an iOS app. App should be Free for first 1 month from installation in the Device. Once the 1 month period is over , user has to subscribe to use the application every month by paying some X amount.

1) Will apple allows such applications ?
2) If allows, how to achieve this kind of Payments ?
3) How to prevent user to access the app after 1 month. (Calculation of the Days)?
4) Should i reinstall the app after subscription ?

Comment: What about disabling some "premium" features in your app, after a period (eg, a month) and then requiring a subscription for those features after that?

Answer (score 1):

IAP is supposed to be used to provide additional content and features to an already functional app.

If you render your app useless or without functionality after a month, it will probably be rejected, or banned after approved. I believe you can't have an app that will simply say "Your trial expired.".

In my opinion, you would need to think of a functionality that you can provide to all users, regardless of they paying for it or not, and have the premium or the extra functionality purchased as a In-App Purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does **not** allow free trials in the app store. If you try to do this, your app will get rejected. Still, there is one category of app where Apple *does* allow a free trial: apps with [auto-renewing subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/subscriptions.html). These were originally intended for (and only allowed with) Newsstand apps where the subscription is for getting new content such as magazine editions etc.

Apple recently allowed the use of auto-renewing subscriptions in non-Newsstand apps but it's still a very grey area as to what exactly Apple will allow with these. Usually the subscription will have to provide some kind of periodic new content in your app. I agree with those who [recommend against using them](http://www.marco.org/2013/12/02/auto-renewable-subscriptions).

Comment: Can you give a reference to Apple recently allowing non-Newstand apps to use auto-renewing subscriptions?

Comment: @ChrisPrince I can't find any official reference at the moment, but see footnote 1 in the Marco Arment blog post I [linked to above](http://www.marco.org/2013/12/02/auto-renewable-subscriptions). See also [another post](http://www.marco.org/2012/01/06/autorenewable-subscription-restrictions) by Marco on the topic. Certainly the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/subscriptions.html) don't explicitly mention Newsstand anywhere any more.

Comment: I'm not sure about Newstand references by Apple, but auto-renewing subscriptions still seem as restrictive as ever. E.g., "11.15 Apps may only use auto renewing subscriptions for periodicals (newspapers, magazines), business Apps (enterprise, productivity, professional creative, cloud storage) and media Apps (video, audio, voice), or the App will be rejected" (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html; retrieved as of 2/19/14)

Comment: @ChrisPrince yes, but AFAIK they were originally exclusive to Newsstand apps, and that's no longer the case, even if the conditions for their use remain very restrictive.